# Does this proof for product estimate in Sobolev spaces work?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

For $u,v\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$, $s,s_1,s_2\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\|uv\|_{H^s}\lesssim_{d,s,s
_1}\|u\|_{H^{s_1}}\|v\|_{H^{s_2}}.
$$
where $s_1+s_2=s+d/2>0$.

**My attempts:** We work in a direct estimate in Fourier side except introducing Bony's decomposition. Indeed,  $$
|(\hat{u}\ast \hat{v})(\xi)|\le \left(\int_{|\eta|\le |\xi-\eta|}+\int_{|\eta|\ge |\xi-\eta|} \right)|\hat{u}(\eta)\hat{v}(\xi-\eta)| \,\mathrm{d}\eta.
$$
For the first term we estimate as $$
\begin{aligned}
& [\int_{|\eta|\le |\xi-\eta|}|\hat{u}(\eta)\hat{v}(\xi-\eta)| \,\mathrm{d}\eta]^2\\
\le&[\int_{|\eta|\le |\xi-\eta|}\langle \eta \rangle^{t} |\hat{u}(\eta)|\cdot \langle \eta \rangle^{-t} |\hat{v}(\xi-\eta)| \,\mathrm{d}\eta]^2 \\ 
\le& \|u\|_{H^t}^2 \int_{|\eta|\le |\xi-\eta|} \langle \eta \rangle^{-2t} |\hat{v}(\xi-\eta)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\eta=\|u\|_{H^t}^2 \int_{|\eta|\ge |\xi-\eta|} \langle \xi-\eta \rangle^{-2t} |\hat{v}(\eta)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\eta\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, $$
\|uv\|_{H^s}^2= \int_{\mathbb R^d}\langle \xi \rangle^{2s}|(\hat{u}\ast \hat{v})(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\xi\le J_1+J_2,
$$
where $$
\begin{aligned}
J_1:&=\|u\|_{H^t}^2  \int_{\mathbb R^d}\langle \xi \rangle^{2s}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{|\xi-\eta|\le |\eta|} \langle \xi-\eta \rangle^{-2t} |\hat{v}(\eta)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\eta \\
&=\|u\|_{H^t}^2 \int_{\mathbb R^d}|\hat{v}(\eta)|^2\,\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{|\xi-\eta|\le |\eta|} \langle \xi-\eta \rangle^{-2t}  \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}\,\mathrm{d}\xi.
\end{aligned}
$$
The last integral can be estimated as $$
\int_{B(\eta,|\eta|)} \langle \eta-\xi \rangle^{-2t} \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\lesssim \langle \eta \rangle^{d+2s-2t}(\forall s,t\in\mathbb R).
$$
Thus we obtain $$
J_1\lesssim \|u\|_{H^t}^2 \|v\|_{H^{\frac{d}{2}+s-t}}^2.
$$
If we adapt the step for $J_2$ to obtain the same estimate, the proof is complete.

***However*** I could not find any step in the proof requires the condition $s_1+s_2>0$. Is there anything wrong in the proof? Or the proof is right but it can't be generalized to the case when $u,v$ are in negative Sobolev spaces, so that they are not necessarily to be functions?

**24.03.29 Updated**: The problem comes from the last integral, for estimate of which requires $s>-d/2$ and $t<d/2$. We spilt the ball into three areas: $$
A_1:=B(0,|\eta|/2)\cap B(\eta,|\eta|), A_2:=B(\eta,|\eta|/2),A_3:=B(\eta,|\eta|)\setminus(A_1\cup A_2).
$$
In $A_1$ we have $|\eta|/2\le|\eta-\xi|\le|\eta|$, hence $$
\int_{A_1} \langle \eta-\xi \rangle^{-2t} \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\sim \langle \eta \rangle^{-2t}\int_{A_1} \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\le \langle \eta \rangle^{-2t} I(s,|\eta|/2),
$$
where $$I(s,R):=\int_{B(0,R)} \langle \xi \rangle^{2s} \,\mathrm{d}\xi.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\int_{A_2} \langle \eta-\xi \rangle^{-2t} \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\sim\langle \eta \rangle^{2s} I(-t,|\eta|/2),
$$
and $$
\int_{A_3} \langle \eta-\xi \rangle^{-2t} \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\sim \langle \eta \rangle^{2s-2t}|A_3|\sim \langle \eta \rangle^{d+2s-2t}.
$$
We are on the stage to deal with $I(s,R)$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $R>0$. However the estimate $$
I(s,R)\lesssim \langle R \rangle^{d+2s}
$$
only holds for $s>-d/2$. Hence the proof collapsed if $s\le -d/2$ or $t\ge d/2$. Conclusively, the proof above  $$
\|uv\|_{H^s}\lesssim_{d,s,s
_1}\|u\|_{H^{s_1}}\|v\|_{H^{s_2}}
$$ only applies when $s_1+s_2>0$, $s\le s(s_1,s_2)$ where $$
s(s_1,s_2)=\begin{cases}
s_1+s_2-d/2, \min\{s_1,s_2\}<d/2,\\
\max\{s_1,s_2\}-\epsilon, \min\{s_1,s_2\}\ge d/2.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: How do you get the last integral majoration ?

Comment: @LL 3.14 Corrected. Thanks for reading the proof and the comment.